# Train feedforward neural network

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I have a feedforward neural network, his goal is to learn how to play to a game (in exemple, the connect 4). I would like to train my neural network by playing games against itself.

My problem is, I don't know how to train my neural network. If I had another good algorithm which determines the best move for a given board, it would be, in my mind, easier, but I don't want to use this way.

So, I don't know if a move is a good move or not, I only know which player won (the neural network play both player, but I know if it's the first or the second player who won), and the moves played during the game.

At the moment, I wrote a program in Go which initialize a neural network, can check if a board of connect 4 is win or not, calcul the output of the neural network according to the board and you can play against the neural network, or let it play against itself. For me, I just need of a function which train my neural network at the end of a game ? 
There is what I did : https://github.com/Julien2313/connectFour

Comment: This question fits better to the [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes, I didn't know this part of the forum. So, I delete this post and copy/past it in Cross Validated ?

Comment: @julien2312, yes please. There you have more chance to get a proper answer.

Comment: Hi @julien2313 it would be great if you can provide what you have done. Don't go to Stats SE as they would ask you to provide your steps

Comment: @Lati don't ask Julien to go to Stats SE. Julien is looking for technical help on his programmation, not stats questions.

Comment: @julien2313 don't forget to add the tag for your program

Comment: @julien2313 for your future questions http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @AndyK, I thought julien wants to ask more like theory but programming since no language or library is mentioned. julien, if you have already some coding please edit your post and add some more informative tags

Comment: I know @Lati what you mean, I thought about it and people on Stats SE would have asked him to provide the steps too. Better deal with Julien's question here and ask him the relevant info rather than passing the baby to another site

Comment: At the moment, I wrote a program in Go which initialize a neural network, can check if a board of connect 4 is win or not, calcul the output of the neural network according to the board and you can play against the neural network, or let it play against itself. For me, I just need of a function which train my neural network at the end of a game ?
If you want, there is the program :
https://github.com/Julien2313/connectFour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a neural network (or in fact any supervised learning method) for autonomous game playing, you need to determine a numerical or categorical value that the algorithm can learn.

One potential solution would be to map *game state* to *actions*. Another would be to map *game state* to *score*. But in some games these may not be possible to learn (Connect 4 has no score), or data may not be readily available. In this situation supervised learning algorithms cannot (or at least *should not*) be used.

Another framework for machine learning exists called *Reinforcement Learning* that handles this problem quite elegantly. Instead of providing a neural network with labelled data, you can train an algorithm to pick moves (or actions) throughout the game providing only a 1 if the algorithm (agent) won and a -1 if the agent lost.

The most popular algorithm (although perhaps not the best) in this framework is Q-Learning. In fact, it is common to combine Q-Learning with Deep Neural Networks to play incredibly challenging games. This is roughly the same set up Google's Deepmind including David Silver used to beat Lee Sedol at Go.

I would suggest a study of Richard Sutton's [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html) to learn more about this subject, however for a faster learning experience Wikipedia's Q-learning article may suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I read a little bit about reinforcement learning, and I think it's what a want to do. I already wanted to use deep neural networks. So, now I know the name of the type of learning, it will be easier to find ways to train my neural network ! Thank you !